# No election/appointed date on moderators page on meta sites

Tags: bug, moderators, per-site-meta

I noticed that moderators page on per-site metas doesn’t have elected/appointed date. E.g. on ELL site:

[Main:](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)

> [image: main]

[Meta:](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)

> [image: meta]

This looks buggy for me. If it’s intentional I would like to see an explanation.